# NetBeans IDE Code completion shortcut

Tags: java, netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts

I have two problems.

First when i type code, netbeans automatically completes the brackets. Now what i need is to move cursor out of brackets to type the semicolon. I have to do it with the right arrow key, but i have seen tutorials in which coders to it faster. Is there some other short key or a way to do it quicker i.e from the keys under my hands?

Second the Netbeans suggestion are quite slow in my machine. Is there a way to make them load faster?

Comment: Well found the answer to the first question. It does it automatically. when the cursor is inside brackets like (|), you press the key for ; and it will automatically move out and insert a ;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also, `CTRL-;` adds a semicolon at the end of the current line, without moving the cursor.  The shortcut can be changed: Menu Tools -> Options -> Keymap and search for "Complete line".

There is also in the keymap an option for "Complete line and create new line", which does the same but then puts the cursor at the start of a newly created line below.  By default, I had no mapping to it, but I added it as `CTRL-SHIFT-;`.

Answer (score 0):

Type the closed backet. Netbeans realizes what's going on and does exactly what you describe.